# Python Request Token from REST API

Tags: python, api, request, restful-authentication

Im struggling with this Dokumentation [here](https://1nce.com/en/help-center/tutorials-documentations/api-functionality/):

- Send your credential base64 encoded to the authentication server.
- Get a response including an UUID for authentication.
- Use the UUID to authenticate REST requests.

It shows this request as an example:

```
**Header**

“`json

{

‘Content-Type’: ‘application/x-www-form-urlencoded’,

‘authorization’: ‘Basic <base64 encoded username:password>’

 }

 “`

 **Body**

 “`json

 {

 ‘grant_type’: ‘client_credentials’

 }

 “`
```

How do I turn with into a requests.post() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to build dictionaries and post them with requests :

```
import requests
import base64
import json

username = "user"
password = "password"
url = 'https://myurl.com'

headers = {}
headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
headers['authorization'] = 'Basic ' + base64.b64encode(bytes(username + ':' + password, 'utf-8')).decode('utf-8')

body = {}
body['grant_type'] = 'client_credentials'

r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(body), headers=json.dumps(headers))
```